# CRON + GIT auth problem: ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: git, github, ssh, cron

I have a raspberry pi setup with python script that periodically checks a directory and uploads changes to github using SSH connection.

Script works ok if I start it in the shell.
SSH works.
If I type `ssh -T git@github.com` in the shell, I get success message "You've successfully authenticated ..."

I still experience problems when I would like to autostart script on boot using crontab.

`eval`ssh-agent -s`&& ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa && ssh-add -l && sudo -u pi ssh -T git@github.com`

I get the following error: ssh: could not resolve hostname github.com: temporary failure in name resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I found suitable solution:
`@reboot sleep 60 && evalssh-agent -s&& ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa && ssh-add -l && sudo -u pi ssh -T git@github.com`

So adding 60s timeout helped as ssh is not booted yet when crontab starts running scripts.

Comment: It's not ssh itself that is not yet up, but rather the name resolution system, but that's pretty much the workaround. There's no reliable way to wait for DNS to be ready in general, unfortunately.